# Tangent bundle to a simple manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the manifold of interest. So $\mathcal{M}$ = $\mathbb{R}$. We define a coordinate $x$ which gives us a point on the manifold.

The tangent plane to $\mathcal{M}$ at a point $x=p$, $T_p\mathcal{M}$ is given as $\mathbb{R}$.

Is it true then that the tangent bundle is the union of all tangent planes at every point $p$ in $\mathcal{M}$? In this case, is it true that $T\mathcal{M} = \mathbb{R}^2$?

What I am confused about is the fact that my instructor uses the tangent bundle to define the basis vector for $\mathcal{M}$. My problem with this is that, by this perspective, I believe that $T\mathcal{M}$ should equal $\mathbb{R} \times 1$. What's correct here?

Comment: It is true that $T\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 1):

I've always known the definition of tangent bundle to be

$$
T\mathcal{M} \;\; =\;\; \{(p,v) \; | \; p \in \mathcal{M}, \; v \in T_p\mathcal{M}\}.
$$

Since the tangent space at every point of $\mathbb{R}$ is another copy of $\mathbb{R}$ it should be that $T\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The tangent space at every point of the sphere is $\Bbb R^2$, but the tangent bundle of the sphere is not isomorphic, or even diffeomorphic, to $S^2 \times \Bbb R^2$. In this case, though, it is true that the tangent bundle of $\Bbb R$ is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ (and is isomorphic as a vector bundle to the trivial rank 1 bundle over $\Bbb R$)

Comment: @MikeMiller Is there an alternative definition that is more suitable to the OP's question?  I'm not sure how your comment clarifies.